# Redirect user to another stateful widget after succesful authentication

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

After spending countless hours I've finally come up with proper solution where the user is authenticated successfully as I can see on idToken on firebase and on console. However the user is not redirected to another widget even after being written in the code.

And how can I access user details on other classes?

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => MyApp();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      'email',
    ],
    hostedDomain: '',
    clientId: '',
    );


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
          home: _googleSignIn.isSignedIn() != null ? Home(): SignInScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {

  Future<void> _googleSignUo() async{
    try{
      final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
        scopes: [
          'email',
        ],
        hostedDomain: '',
        clientId: '',
      );
      final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

      final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken
      );

      final FirebaseUser user = (await (_auth.signInWithCredential(credential))) as FirebaseUser;

      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Signed in');
      return Home();
    }catch(e){
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: OutlineButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0)),
              onPressed: ()=> {
                _googleSignUo()
            },
           child:Text('   Sign In with Google',
       style: TextStyle(
         fontSize: 20
       ),
      )
     );
    }
}
```

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      'email',
    ],
    hostedDomain: '',
    clientId: '',
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                _googleSignIn.signOut();
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SignInScreen()));

              },
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
 );
  }
}
```

Comment: you have many many misconcepts in your code and some errors (returnin null as a home of material app), check this blog for a tidier approach https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-how-to-do-user-login-with-firebase-a6af760b14d5

Comment: the article is up to date, and here is an article about google sign in  I recommend you to check and it is up to date :)


https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-implementing-google-sign-in-71888bca24ed

Comment: @LoVe thanks, it works now. I've been looking for a proper article or tutorial for 3rd day today. I'll still be testing the functionality thoroughly.

Comment: @LoVe the code in the article worked for me, however everytime I open the app. It takes me to the ```SignInScreen()```. Being a complete noob. I tried conditions and switch case with ```RootPage``` but failed. Any help here?

Comment: you followed the code in the article and still can't implement the sign-in?I recommend you to follow their way and give up your code bcz it has many bad practices

Comment: @LoVe I'm following the second article you sent and it has worked for me and I'm using the code in my project but if you check it out, there's no code where if the user is logged in, it saves information and shows home screen instead of login screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212141/discussion-between-love-and-codekls).